# Viewing and filtering models: admin panel or not admin panel?

Tags: python, django

I am fairly new to Django, though I delved into other web frameworks in the past.

I am in a case where I need to view all instances of a model, be able to interactively sort and filter them through various criterias and execute an arbitratry treatment to the selected objects.

My initial approach would be to use the admin panel, since it seems to provide out of the box the features I'm looking for, plus authentication (as you can guess, I'm trying to set up a back office of some sort).

Nevertheless, I feel admin panels are essentially designed for another kind of use cases, and using them like that would be bad form (heh, "form"... nevermind). The end of this [chapter](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html) of the Django book seems to confirm this feeling, too.

Is this the right way to go, or should I look into writing something from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go django admin with no second thoughts. It provides 100% what you're looking for and it suits model-editing applications. Building something from scratch would be an extremely time intensive process. Also your final code would probably do things that admin already does, possibly in a less efficient way.

Even if you have no experience with the django admin application, the learning curve is not as high as developing a new interface + you will know how to use it in future projects.

I would just register the admin site with no admin prefix, and start from there :)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Side note: if you want to spice up the admin app you can check out various 3rd party applications that extend it, like grapelli or yawd-admin.

Answer (score 0):

Admin in django is extremely powerful and flexible. You can define custom actions, validations, override the save methods, override default template etc. So it is advisable to modify the admin to suit your needs rather than writing one from scratch.